# Make children fill parent max-width inside an absolute context

Tags: html, css, absolute

I have something equivalent to the second case (div group) of this simplified example, the first one is just to show that it works outside of an absolute context with the child expanding as much as it can until it reaches the parent max-width:

```css
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}

.parent {
  /*
    This div is reused across the web with different dynamic content
    Its only constraint to the children should be a maximum width
  */
  max-width: 300px;
}

.child {
  /*+
    This is one of the multiple children the parent will have
    In this case it should should always try to grow as much as allowed by its parent
  */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    Foo
  </div>
</div>

<div class='abs'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
      Bar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Given that the absolute div is mandatory for my specific needs, is there any way to make a child element fill its parent max-width?

Comment: Width calculation for absolute positioned elements is shrink-to-fit, so your div here has no reason to become any wider than the "Bar" text demands.

Comment: But why can't the class 'abs' be 100% width? That is the one that decides the width..

Comment: @CBroe if that's the case, is there any way to override that behavior?

Comment: @Wimanicesir my abs div is an element (something similar to a modal dialog, so you can picture it in your head) that is reused across my app and can't (and probably shouldn't) decide its own width, as it should be determined by the children needs in every different use case

Comment: _"can't (and probably shouldn't) decide its own width, as it should be determined by the children needs"_ - but your children _don't_ need more than the width of the word "Bar" in that example - so that's a catch-22.

Comment: @CBroe I could update the example to be more real world based, but it is supposed to be just an example. In my real case, I have to render a search bar input that will then render a list of results below it. This results have variable width: some bigger than the max-width, some smaller. I can't rely on this results because then the width would be constantly changing as the content changes, and also an empty input (the initial state) doesn't need any space until you write. Hardcoding the width to be the same as the max-width is a possibility but we all can agree it probably is a bad practice

Comment: I can't see why that would be a bad practice. You appear to _want_ a (min-)width here, so why should you refuse to specify one then?

Comment: I need a stable width, a min-width smaller than the parent max-width will still cause layout shifting, which is specially painful when it involves a text input.

Manually specifying the same width as the parent max-width is bad in terms of mantainability and reusability: if I ever want to change the parent max-width I have to account the children in this use case, and if I want to use the children (which is its own component in my *app*) outside of this absolute context I now have to deal with an arbitrary width that might not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning?source=post_page) states:

> **Absolutely positioned elements will shrink-wrap to fit their contents unless you specify their dimensions**. You can specify the width by setting the left and right properties, or by setting the width property. You can specify the height by setting the top and bottom properties, or by setting the height property.

Therefore, you need to specify width for your absolute element.

```css
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    Foo
  </div>
</div>

<div class='abs'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
      Bar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I assume that you are using some framework to accomplish your task - specifying the width can be placed inside components stylesheet, so each of the components which eventually uses it can provide preferred width (and other styling as well)